# php header not working online but working on my localhost.....why?

Tags: php

This works perfectly well on my localhost but when i hosted online, it does not logon and it echo logged on successful and error free. Pls what can be the cause for this?

```
<?php
session_start();
           $_SESSION['user_logged']=$user;
             $_SESSION['user_password']=$password;
                      $user = $_POST["username"];    
                        $password = $_POST["password"];


include("include/connect.php");
$msg = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$val){
 $$key=$val;
}

if(count($msg)==0){

$sql="SELECT username, password FROM admin WHERE username='$username' && password='$password'";
$res=mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_fetch_array($res)>0){
    $_SESSION['user_logged']= $user;
    $_SESSION['user_password']=$password;   
    header("location:dashboard.php");
    echo "You looged in Successfully";
    }  else{
    $msg[]='Incorrect username/password';
    }

 }

    } 
 ?>
```

Below is the dashboard.php which its suppose to redirect to.

```
 <?php 
 include('include/connect.php');
 include('include/function.php');
 if(isset($_REQUEST['mode']) )
    {
  $mode=$_REQUEST['mode'];
if($mode == 1)
{
     $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
     $sql="DELETE FROM enquiry WHERE id='$id'";
     $result=mysql_query($sql);
    }
   }
 $msg=array();
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$title=$_POST['news'];
$news_item=$_POST['news'];
if(empty($news_item)){
    $msg[]='You must enter news in the column!';
}
if(empty($title)){
    $msg[]='News Title must not be empty!';
}

    else {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news_file WHERE title='$title' ";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_array($res);
if($result > 0){
    $msg[] = 'News with the same title has been added already';

}  else {

 $sql = "INSERT INTO news_file (title,news,date) VALUES ('$title','$news_item',Now())";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);   

     $msg[]='News was successfully added';

}

}

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Why do you have an echo statement after your redirect? Does that seem right to you?

Comment: i only want to use that to check if anything is really happening cos the page just reload and stays back on the login form. thanks

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using on the Live Server compared with the localhost? the `mysql_connect()` function has been deprecated and should be replaced with PDO or similar.

Comment: but i used the same mysql_connect for other parts of the code and it works. This is also working, only that the header is not redirecting well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
session_start();
    /*
        These should be the other way round, as you are setting
        the session variables with variables which have not been
        initialised yet
    */
    $user = $_POST["username"];    
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $_SESSION['user_logged']=$user;
    $_SESSION['user_password']=$password;

include("include/connect.php");
$msg = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$val){
 $key=$val; // Removed Erroneous double $
}

if(count($msg)==0){

$sql="SELECT 
        username, 
        password 
      FROM 
        admin 
      WHERE 
        username='$username' 
      AND 
        password='$password'"; 
      // MySql does not accept && as a comparison operator.
$res=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$res)
{
    var_dump(mysql_error());
    exit;
}
else
{

    if(mysql_fetch_array($res)>0)
    {
        $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
        while(mysql_fetch_array($res)>0)
        {
            $_SESSION['user_logged']= $user;
            $_SESSION['user_password']=$password;   
            header("location:dashboard.php");
            echo "You logged in Successfully";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        msg[]='Incorrect username/password';
    }
}
?>
```

Looking at the code you have provided for `dashboard.php`, you are expecting there to be `$_POST` data, for a page which you have redirected to. Where you have redirected to the page, there will be no `$_POST` data for you to retrieve from the server.

I have amended my script above, to store the `$_POST` data in the session, so using that, you should be able to call your news items by calling `$_SESSION['post']['news']`, or if this is too long winded, simply re-assign the POST data once inside your `dashboard.php` script like so.

`$post = $_SESSION['post'];`

Then you can call it by using `$post['news']`.

Comment: i tired this, it only load an empty page and not going to the dashboard.

Comment: Are the session variables available to you on the dashboard? Without seeing what the dashboard does, it is difficult to troubleshoot the "why's" of the problem.

Comment: i have added the dashboard.php  to the script where the header is suppose to redirect to.

Comment: Pls anyone with any help on this yet, Will really appreciate if somone can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: I have amended my answer for you now. Please let me know if this helps.